# Need to replace a 5 digit number in specific lines that has specific word in it (notepad ++)

Tags: notepad++

```
<MouseMovementEvent>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <X>24848</X>
      <Y>27245</Y>
      <Delay>2</Delay>
    </MouseMovementEvent>
    <MouseMovementEvent>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <X>24814</X>
      <Y>27245</Y>
      <Delay>3</Delay>
    </MouseMovementEvent>
    <MouseMovementEvent>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <X>24780</X>
      <Y>27245</Y>
      <Delay>1</Delay>
    </MouseMovementEvent>
    <MouseMovementEvent>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <X>24370</X>
      <Y>27306</Y>
      <Delay>17</Delay>
    </MouseMovementEvent>
    <MouseMovementEvent>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <X>24336</X>
      <Y>27366</Y>
```

So in this example, I need to replace all 5-digit numbers in the lines that start with `<Y>`

Comment: you see, there is random numbers in the line with '<Y>' I need to replace all of them with 27245 and there is about 2000 lines in the original code

Comment: It's pretty basic, except that [you should not parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Find: `<Y>\d+` Replace `<Y>27245`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer could easily be found in any regex tutorial.